# how to list available monitors in c++ windows 7?

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to get the attached monitors in windows 7 using c++, the code I am using is as follows

```
void ListDisplayDevices()
{
    int index=0;
    DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
    dd.cb = sizeof(DISPLAY_DEVICE);

    while (EnumDisplayDevices(NULL, index++, &dd, 0))
    {
        if (dd.StateFlags & DISPLAY_DEVICE_PRIMARY_DEVICE) printf("* ");
        printf("%s, %s\n", dd.DeviceName, dd.DeviceString);
    }
}
```

but the output of this function is simply

```
* \, A
\, A
\, A
\, R
\, R
\, R
\, V
```

What may be wrong here?

Comment: Possibly you are compiling this for unicode so the strings are unicode strings which you are trying to print as single byte strings. I *think* that windows has a printf format of "%S" (upper case) that will print this. So if this is the problem either try switching to a non-unicode build or try this perhaps?

Comment: Thanks @J99, I used %ls as the DISPLAY_DEVICE is giving wchar_t type, now its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Her is my attempt:

```
int main()
{
       DISPLAY_DEVICE dd;
       dd.cb = sizeof(dd);
       int deviceIndex = 0;
       // la première fois, on parcours les adapteurs video
       while (EnumDisplayDevices(0, deviceIndex, &dd, 0))
       {
             // deviceName contient ici le nom d'une carte video
             std::string deviceName = dd.DeviceName;
             int monitorIndex = 0;
             DISPLAY_DEVICE ddMonitor;
             ddMonitor.cb = sizeof(ddMonitor);
             // la deuxième fois on parcours les moniteurs pour chaque adapteur video
             while (EnumDisplayDevices(deviceName.c_str(), monitorIndex, &ddMonitor, 0))
             {
                    // ici Devicename contient le nom d'un moniteur
                    std::cout << "Nom moniteur = " << ddMonitor.DeviceName << std::endl;
                    ++ monitorIndex;
             }
             ++deviceIndex;
       }
       return 0;
}
```

It outputs the following on a single-monitor computer:

`Nom moniteur = \\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0`