# how to get a list of available monitors in windows 10

Tags: c++, winapi

I want to get a list of available monitors in Windows 10, same as the monitor list shown in the System display settings (no matter whether they are attached or unattached), just like this:

[image]

I use `EnumDisplayDevices()` to enumerate all displays, but there is no proper flag indicating whether the display is available.

So, how can I do this?

Comment: Note: Microsoft does not document how the numbers in the display dialog maps to the actual devices/hmonitors.

Answer (score 1):

`EnumDisplayDevices` appears to return pseudo-devices too.
According to [EnumDisplayMonitors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-enumdisplaymonitors)  documentation you can use [GetSystemMetrics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getsystemmetrics) (SM_CMONITORS) to filter out pseudo devices and receive a list of physical devices only.

Potentially a similar question [how to list available monitors in c++ windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13700852/how-to-list-available-monitors-in-c-windows-7) helps you too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the result is not expected:Nom moniteur = \\.\DISPLAY1\Monitor0
Nom moniteur = \\.\DISPLAY2\Monitor0
Nom moniteur = \\.\DISPLAY16\Monitor0
Nom moniteur = \\.\DISPLAY16\Monitor1
Nom moniteur = \\.\DISPLAY17\Monitor0
Nom moniteur = \\.\DISPLAY17\Monitor1
................
Nom moniteur = \\.\DISPLAY31\Monitor0
Nom moniteur = \\.\DISPLAY31\Monitor1,I only want DISPLAY1/2/16/17,exclude 18-31.

Comment: DISPLAY16/17 is monitor3/4 in the picture, not attached, virtual monitor(indirect display driver).

Comment: How exactly is GetSystemMetrics going to help you filter? It only knows the count, there is no way to pass it a monitor handle...

Answer (score 0):

`EnumDisplayDevices` gives you the `DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP` and `DISPLAY_DEVICE_MIRRORING_DRIVER` flags. `MONITORINFOEX` gives you the device name to compare with when mapping from `HMONITOR`.

Answer (score 0):

The [QueryDisplayConfig](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig) function retrieves information about all possible display paths for all display devices, or views, in **the current setting**. You can try [the document example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig#examples).
[More information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/display/querydisplayconfig-summary-and-scenarios#querydisplayconfig-scenarios).